# Which software is used to make beautiful illustrative youtube video like this?

Tags: youtube

I really like the smooth fluid illustrative animations as shown in this YouTube video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNUz1-msbOM&t=142s&ab_channel=ByteByteGo).

Could anyone tell me which software (probably) is used to make such illustrations?

I am thinking of creating some educational videos myself. So I think such illustrations would really help the audience understand complex concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some of them can be made by using something like PowerPoint and the Morph transition, or Keynote and the Magic Move transition, and then combining them with iMovie.

Others might need something like Apple's [Motion](https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/), or the open-source [Natron](https://natrongithub.github.io) to be done.